# Dependency Injection on an android service

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, roboguice

I'm developing an Android app and using Roboguice 2.0.

All has gone incrediblby well, except now. I'm trying to inject my custom bindings to a service like this and it's not working.

```
    @Inject
private TicketService ticketService;

@Inject
private PerformanceService performanceService;
```

They've binded like this (first is custom app context):

```
 RoboGuice.setBaseApplicationInjector(
            this, 
            RoboGuice.DEFAULT_STAGE,
            Modules.override(RoboGuice.newDefaultRoboModule(this))
                .with(
                    new KoliseoModule(),
                    new DatastoreModule(this),
                    new ServiceModule()
                    ));


 public class ServiceModule extends AbstractModule {

@Override
protected void configure() {
      bind(JsonCheckinTimestampService.class).to(JsonCheckinTimestampServiceImpl.class);
    bind(PerformanceService.class).to(PerformanceServiceImpl.class);
    bind(ShowService.class).to(ShowServiceImpl.class);
    bind(TicketService.class).to(TicketServiceImpl.class);
    bind(ValidationStatisticsService.class).to(ValidationStatisticsServiceImpl.class);
}
```

}

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is not working? Where in your code is the setBaseApplicationInjector statement? Is there a specific reaason you use this statement, rather than just a list of modules files in an xml file?

Comment: Didn't know it can be done this way.

Comment: But this doesn't solve my problem and I have to do it manually

Comment: RoboGuice.getInjector(context).getInstance(PerformanceService.class);

Comment: and the problem is that I get null all the time on the injected resources

Comment: in res you can add a file roboguice_modules.xml with a string-array containing the names of your modules, fully specified.

Answer (score 1):

It's very probably and probably even garanteed that the Application subclass of an application is loaded & instantiated before the rest of the instances are created so you could try that.
Create a "MyApplication extends Application" class and do your setup in its "onCreate()", don't forget to declare in your manifest.